# what is the issue with the following code as I am receiving 'w' is not defined?

Tags: c++

I wrote this class. I do not know why i am receiving that w is not defined, although I defined that. Do you know what is the problem?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class add{
  public:
    void counter();
    void z();
    string w;
};

void z(){
    cin>>w; 
    getline(cin,w);
    cout<<w;
}


int main(){
    add s;
    s.z();
    cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to write `void add::z(){` when *defining* the member function `void z()`.

Else you're just defining a *global* function `void z()`, and `w` cannot be found. That's what is confusing the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

variable 'w' is defined as member of class add. Class add also has 2 public member functions. In given code z is not implementation of `void add::z()`, but a new global function called z(). Change line `void (){` into `void add::z(){` and it will be fine.